# Javascript closures and variables

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

Can any one tell me why when i get the variable myBrand directy I end up with the default value?
I was just playing with closures and tryed to do something different with the return, basically not puting it in, which gives me the default value that was at the begining

```
const car = ()=>{
   let myBrand = 'generic' //default value
   function printbrand(){console.log(myBrand)}
   return{
    setBrand: (newBrand)=>{myBrand = newBrand},
    getBrand: ()=>{return myBrand},
    getBrandSimple: myBrand,
    usePrinter: ()=> {return printbrand()},
   }
}

var myCar = car()
myCar.setBrand('tesla')
console.log(`Brand with direct = ${myCar.getBrandSimple}`)
     //Output
    // Brand with direct = generic
console.log(`Brand with function = ${myCar.getBrand()}`);
    //Output
   // Brand with function = tesla
console.log(`Brand with printer = `);
myCar.usePrinter()
    //Output
   // Brand with printer = 
  // tesla
console.log(`Brand with direct = ${myCar.getBrandSimple}`)
   //Output
  // Brand with direct = generic
```

Answer (score 1):

`getBrandSimple` contains a *copy* of the *value* of `myBrand` *at the time the object is created*.

It doesn't contain a reference to the variable so when you change the value of the variable, you don't change the value of `getBrandSimple`.